# How to give different title descriptions on the same kind of file to avoid duplicates?

Tags: php, html, xhtml, seo, meta-tags

So basically , Google is treating www.example/cz and example.cz/index.php as two duplicates when they have the same meta descriptions ... So example.com/cz and example.com/cz/index should not have the same meta description.

How can I assign different meta descriptions to example.com/cz and example.com/cz/index.php , I tried to use $_SERVER['self'] in PHP , but it still returns index.php ... How should I tackle this.

Comment: try `REQUEST_URI` instead, which should be the exact address requested.

Comment: Although I understand the question, I still wonder why there are five different URIs in the question, rather than two.

Answer (score 1):

If the same exact content is on both pages, which it seems like might be the case, then it will still be considered duplicate content even if the meta descriptions are unique. I would recommend adding a permanent 301 redirect to the main page. For example:

301 redirect example.com/cz/index.php to example.com/cz/

This will take care of the duplicate content concerns between the 2 pages.